# zabbix 3.0 + pg_monz 2.0 + PostgreSQL streaming replication

Tags: zabbix, system-monitoring, postgresql-replication

I have a Zabbix 3.0 instance on CentOS 7.2, I've added the pg_monz extension for monitoring my PostgreSQL streaming replication.

I currently have this in my Zabbix interface;

- DB1

  - host_groups

    - PostgreSQL
    - Linux Servers
  - templates

    - Template OS Linux
    - Template App PostgreSQL SR
    - Template App PostgreSQL SR Cluster
- DB2

  - host_groups;

    - PostgreSQL
    - Linux Servers
  - templates;

    - Template OS Linux
    - Template App PostgreSQL SR

On the 'latest data' tab, filtered to host_group PostgreSQL

- DB1

  - pg.cluster.status

    - all items greyed out
- DB2

  - pg.cluster.status

    - Number of primary server      1
    - Number of running PostgreSQL server   1
    - Number of standby server      0

Can someone please clarify the setup for monitoring streaming
replication, I'm sure I've mixed something up in my templates.

I would expect DB1 to show one primary, two running postgresql server
and one standby server. The documentation is a little vague for pg_monz.